# Gnome Search Tools

Tags: gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, but with the Gnome Fallback Environment. I remember seeing someone being able to press tab, and have a "results as you go type" search function. How do I do that in Gnome Fallback?

Answer (score 0):

The [Gnome Search Tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/gnome-search-tool.1.html) could be your best solution, installable by clicking on [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-search-tool). You may also like [Synapse](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synapse/).